# Google Maps: Get lat/lng from known start location and given km

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say I know the start lat/lng of highway A and that a construction zone starts at km 175.
Is there a way to calculate the lat/lng at km 175? (Probably with direction service)

Comment: like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)?

Comment: Nice "answer" as usual!

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks. polyline.GetPointAtDistance is actually what I need but I can't find this function in the Polyline API v3.

Comment: It is part of Mike Williams epoly Google Maps Javascript API v2 extension which I ported to v3, my version is referenced in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mike Williams](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) wrote an extension to the [Google Maps Javascript API v2 (now deprecated and turned off)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference) called [epoly](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/epoly.htm) which contains the method .GetPointAtDistance, which does what you want.

[example using a ported version of that library](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_kmmarkersC.html)

partial source code of the GetPointAtDistance function (depends on extending the google.maps.LatLng object with distanceFrom method)

```
/* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a google.maps.LatLng at the specified distance   *
 *                   along the path.                                              *
 *                   The distance is specified in metres                          *
 *                   Returns null if the path is shorter than that                *
 */

// === A method which returns a google.maps.LatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist=0;
  var olddist=0;
  for (var i=1; (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i-1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1= this.getPath().getAt(i-2);
  var p2= this.getPath().getAt(i-1);
  var m = (metres-olddist)/(dist-olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng( p1.lat() + (p2.lat()-p1.lat())*m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng()-p1.lng())*m);
}
```